# Assign all rows and both columns of data to an array

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to return all rows of data of an unknown amount [8 rows] from two columns. I get the *subscript out of range* error for >> `SERnumber(rws, clm)`.

I'm simply trying to return:

```
in  AAA
out AAA
in  AAA
in  VVV
in  GGG
```

Here's my non-working code:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim SERnumber() As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim strMessage As String
Dim rws As Integer
Dim clm As Integer
' assign variable > rws the # of rows containing data
         rws = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
' Redimension the SERnumber array variable >>
' for n? rows and 2 columns
         ReDim SERnumber(1 To rws, clm)

         For i = 1 To rws
               For clm = 1 To 2
                  SERnumber(rws, clm) = Cells(rws, clm).Value
               Next clm
         Next i
' Loop through the array and add the names to a string
        strMessage = "Here are the results:" & vbCrLf
            For i = 0 To rws
               strMessage = strMessage & SERnumber(i) & vbCrLf
            Next 'i
        MsgBox strMessage
End Sub
```

Comment: Your error is because:  `ReDim SERnumber(1 To rws, clm)` declares the 2nd dimension as `0 to 0`.  So in your line `For clm = 1 To 2`, since `clm` bounds are `0 to 0`, your subscript is out of range.  Try changing it to `ReDim SERnumber(1 To rws, 1 to 2)`

Answer (score 1):

You can assign Excel `Range` to VBA Array object as shown in the following VBA code example (`Range` includes entire columns A and B):

```
Sub Range2Array()
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Range("A:B").Value
    'alternatively
     'arr = Range("A:B")
    'test
    Debug.Print (arr(1, 1))
End Sub
```

Such direct assignment to 2d-array has tremendous performance advantage vs using the Range iteration. You can then perform all necessary operations on array elements instead of range cells (it also will be really fast in comparison to iterative range ops).

Another useful technique is to assign Excel's `UsedRange` to VBA Array:

```
arr = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
```

And, the most trivial example (pertinent to your case of 2 columns, 8 rows):

```
arr = Range("A1:B8").Value
```

Hope this will help. Best regards,

Comment: Thanks for your help. Much appreciated but I don't understand your answer. I'm a newbie. It's not you, it's me :)

Comment: I've extended my answer pertinent to your case (2 columns, 8 rows). You can apply this solution to any number of columns/rows (i.e., a direct assignment to VBA array instead of iterating trough the range obj). I hope this will help. If you have more questions then I would recommend to accept this answer and post a separate question(s). Best regards,

Comment: Thank you Alex. I've been experimenting with your code & problem solved.

Comment: You are welcome! Please mark the answer accepted. Good luck with your project. Best regards,